# Suggestions for beginner Rust code

Tags: rust

I just stated learning Rust (again...), here is a short bit of code I wrote:

```
#![allow(non_snake_case)]

/**
 * takes a 2D Vec and returns a 90° rotated version 
 */
pub fn createRotated90(arr: &Vec<Vec<bool>>) -> Vec<Vec<bool>> {
    let newWidth = arr[0].len();
    let newHeight = arr.len();
    let mut newRetArr = createNewFilled2DVec(newWidth as u8, newHeight as u8, false);

    forEachXY(
        newHeight as u8, 
        newWidth as u8, 
        &mut |x: u8, y: u8| newRetArr[y as usize][newHeight - x as usize - 1] = arr[x as usize][y as usize]
    );

    newRetArr
}

pub fn createNewFilled2DVec<T: std::clone::Clone>(width: u8, height: u8, filler: T) -> Vec<Vec<T>> {
    vec![vec![filler; height as usize]; width as usize]
}

pub fn forEachXY<F: FnMut(u8, u8)>(width: u8, height: u8, mut func: F) {
    let mut x: u8 = 0;
    let mut y: u8 = 0;

    while x < width {
        while y < height {
            func(x, y);

            y += 1;
        }

        x += 1;
    }
}
```

I am hoping for some general suggestion on how to improve my "Rusting".
Some points I noticed:

- a lot of `as usize`
- It seems Rust doesn't want me to use "normal" for loops (see `forEachXY`)
- I am using Vec's instead of arrays, even though they don't change in size

Comment: Welcome to Code Review.  Please add an explanation of the purpose of your code.

Comment: @L.F. my code has no real purpose, I just wrote it to get to know Rust

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Correctness

In

```rust
let mut x: u8 = 0;
let mut y: u8 = 0;

while x < width {
    while y < height {
        println!("{}, {}", x, y);
        func(x, y);

        y += 1;
    }

    x += 1;
}
```

`y` increments up to `height`, but then never gets reset. That means that the inner loop only runs once. To fix this, move the initialization of `y` inside the loop, or use a "normal loop" (see below).

---

## Formatting and convention

Right now, it looks like you're trying to write Rust in a different language. Whenever possible, use the conventions suggested by the Rust compiler and the linter `clippy` (run `cargo clippy`). In particular, using `#![allow(non_snake_case)]` to set your own convention is discouraged.

A few other things:

- Use `///` for documentation. `/* */` comments are fairly rare and `///` comments will automatically be included in the documentation produced by `cargo doc`.
- Keep lines fairly short. It's OK to go over the traditional limit of 80 characters sometimes, but whenever possible, break up lines for readability. For example, with a function signature or call, the arguments can be placed on separate lines. `cargo fmt` will do this automatically to the best of its ability.
- `Vec<T>` is itself a pointer (and length and capacity), so `&Vec<T>` has no advantage over `&[T]`. In fact, due to automatic deref coercion, using the latter in a function signature allows that function to take either kind of argument. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o) for more.

---

## Use `for` loops.

When iterating over a collection, `for` loops are usually the best way. There's no need to keep track of mutating variables. If an index is needed, the [`enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate) method in the `Iterator` trait can be used.

Here's how I'd rewrite your loop.

```rust
for (x, col) in arr.iter().enumerate() {
    for (y, &elem) in col.iter().enumerate() {
        new_arr[y][new_height - x - 1] = elem
    }
}
```

---

## Add tests

Before I even touched your code, I made sure to add at least one test case. That alone caught the bug that I mentioned above. Adding more was very helpful when figuring out how the width and height worked (see the first item in Miscellaneous below). Just as a template, you can use

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    fn my_test() {
        // Use things like `assert!` and `assert_eq!` to verify the output of your functions
        // ...
    }
}
```

Tests can be run with `cargo test`.

---

## Miscellaneous

This may just be personal preference, but when I see a 2-dimensional array like

```rust
vec![
    vec![1, 2, 3],
    vec![4, 5, 6],
]
```

I think of this has having a width of 3 and a height of 2. That is, the first row is `[1, 2, 3]` and the second row is `[4, 5, 6]`. Indexing at `(x, y)` is `arr[y][x]` (first access `y`th row, then `x`th column). From what I can tell, you've reversed this. For example, `vec![vec![filler; height as usize]; width as usize]` would have a height of `width` and a width of `height` in my convention.

Note that rotating the vector switches the role of `height` and `width`, so `new_width` is the height of the original and `new_height` is the width of the original.

---

The `u8`/`usize` problems were largely solved by rewriting the loop, but in general, I'd suggest just sticking with one type. There's no reason for `create_new_filled_2d_vec` or `for_each_xy` to take `u8` arguments. That just leads to unnecessary conversions. Since the length of a vector is always `usize`, it makes sense to just use `usize` everywhere.

---

If you want to use arrays, you'll eventually be able to use `const` generics to accomplish this. For now, they'll need to be dynamically allocated as `Box<[T]>`. You can produce a `Box<[T]>` from a `Vec<T>` using the `as_boxed_slice` method. Since the only difference between this and `Vec<T>` is the `capacity` field, `Box<[T]>` is fairly rare in practice. The benefit isn't very large.